# Selected em select dinâmico

Tags: php

Como faço para criar um atributo `selected` apenas no ano atual no `<select>` que tenho abaixo? *Como estamos em 2018, o `<option>` selecionado deverá ser 2018.*

```
<select>
  <?php
    $ano_atual = date("Y");
    for($i = 2014; $i <= $ano_atual; $i++) {
      echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<select>
  <?php
    $ano_atual = date("Y");
    for ($i = 2014; $i <= $ano_atual; $i++) {
      $selected = (intval($ano_atual) === $i) ? 'selected' : '';

      echo "<option value=\"$i\" $selected>$i</option>\n";
    }
  ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Show, valeu brow!

Comment: Me ajudou muito, valeu @LuizFelipe